# Site statistics over time

Tags: support

Is there a way to see SQA statistics (e.g. number of visitors and number of active participants) over time?  It would be interesting to see how the site is changing ( and how or whether it is growing).

Comment: Still hungry, nearly a decade later. Any news on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an interesting question.

There are some analytics available to moderators, but unfortunately only generalities are allowed to be made public.

We're up in both visits and answers over last month, but down slightly in questions. Visits seem to be coming in heavily from search engines, which makes explains why more answers than questions.

So the growth area that is needed is definitely the questions. According to area51, a typical site will get 90% of its traffic from search engines, so we're on target there, which gives users their first question - the one they search. Our area of focus needs to be user's second question: the one they didn't come for but are interested in anyway. Those are what make them stay.

Comment: Although Bruce's answer was the most flattering, this one was the most detailed.

Comment: I never said I disagree with Bruce =)

Comment: Reminder to those who read comments in meta sites: it is ok to answer your own questions (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and in fact it is even encouraged.  Of course, we still want the same kind of high-quality questions that we want when you do not plan to supply your own answer.

Comment: Indeed. SE is not intended for idle questions, but rather real problems being faced. It's expected that the asker will also be working through the problem while others are also assisting. It is quite common to find the answer on your own (with our without guidance from the responses) and it only makes sense to post an answer if you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, but it is available for moderators only ... of which you should probably be one as well.